# Excel Chart to not show columns with blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I find this is a difficult question to name/describe, I have searched similar to the above but I've not managed to find anything that quite addresses this specific situation.

We have financial data formatted with periods as columns and the fields as rows (image 1).

There is a graph output page that needs to be able to vary the financial periods that it can see.  Due to the number of charts, we do not want to have to alter the data ranges of the charts each time the number of periods changes.

I have therefore created another tab in the same structure, with formulae only returning values if it falls within the range selected (image 2).  The range of the charts is then set to the maximum number of columns that we would have.

The problem is that the charts will still return the blank columns even though there is no data (image 3).  If the axis are set to date format then it is smart enough not to do this however we are unable to do so and therefore the axis is text.

Is there a way to have the chart only see the cells that contain data?  Perhaps something with name manager?

Normally this would have been PivotTable and slicer territory but the data unfortunately needs to be in the wrong orientation (periods as columns and data fields as rows).

**Image 1 - Raw Data**

[image: IMG:]

**Image 2 - Calculated Chart Data**

[image: IMG:]

**Image 3- Chart**

[image: IMG:]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see the blank data on the chart (image 3) but not on the data (image 2), Can you tell which number or period on image 2 that show the blank data?

Comment: Apologies, the image 2 didn't extend to show blank data.  The following is a better image where I have restricted the data to 2 periods.  This is controlled by A2 & A3 which reference the columns to be used from the full data tab.  The chart is looking at a maximum range that I have set (E:BC) with only E:F being populated in the following image.  The original screenshot was populated from E:AI.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5sl4.png

Comment: @Daniel-Barnes I've edited your question (which you can do at any time using the `edit` link below it) to replace image 2 with the new one you've provided in your comment above. Hopefully this makes it easier for folks to think about the question.But I notice it refers to a different year, so you may wish to make a further clarifying edit. It's more likely someone can help if everything's complete and consistent in the question itself, which is what people see first.

Comment: I notice you say, "If the axis are set to date format then it is smart enough not to do this" but then "however we are unable to do so". Can you explain what you mean by unable to do so?

Comment: @RegEdit This is due to the merged months shown in Image 3 (Mar/Apr).  Up until this point a date format was possible.